# How to get documentation link in ESS R?

Tags: ess, r

In RStudio, the documentation pane display not just the help file but also links to other help files (see link to `aov` below).

How to get the same in ESS R?

[image: Rstudio doc]

Comment: This feature isn't provided by ESS. In a help buffer typing `h` will prompt you, with completion, for a new help topic. If point is on `aov` when you do this, `aov` will be the default completion provided. Which isn't as nice as just clicking on the link, but it's the best thing available without writing your own function.

Comment: typing `h` is very helpful. The RStudio-style links also help with discoverability. In any case, good to know that there's currently no solution.

Answer (score 2):

If reading the documentation in your browser instead of directly within Emacs works for you, you can use the html help files instead of the text files by configuring your `.Rprofile`:

Simply replace:

```
## set the default help type
options(help_type = "text")
```

by:

```
## set the default help type
options(help_type = "html")
```

This is what your example help file will look like:

[image]

and it has active hyperlinks.

(Note that this does not require any internet connection since the html files come with R).